# Set the Attribute of Telerik grid client template Check box through jquery

Tags: jquery, telerik

I want to change the Attribute (checked) of Telerik grid client template check box after selecting the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use JQuery for this as all the functionality you require is provided by the Telerik client side API. I would start by adding a client side event handler to your `RadGrid` by adding something like the following to the markup:

```
<ClientEvents OnRowSelected="jsRowSelected" />
```

The applicable [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-onrowselected.html) can then be used to determine what data you are passed to make this easier, in this instance the `gridDataItem` from here you can (hopefully) manipulate the row as follows:

```
function jsRowSelected(sender, eventArgs) {
    var cell = eventArgs.gridDataItem.get_cell("chkSelect"); // use the name of your column here
     var ctrls = cell.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (ctrls .length > 0) {
         ctrls[0].checked = true; // I've got it setting the value to "checked" but you might want to do something else
     }
}
```

I've not syntax or error checked the above so in the (likely) event that it doesn't work the following functionality could be used to get the required item: The `get_selectedItems` method from the grids `MasterTableView` (see [this guide](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-cell-values-for-selected-rows-client-side.html)) allows you to get the selected data items; from the selected row you can navigate to the column using `getCellByColumnUniqueName` method. Here you could either look at using the `findControl` (see [this guide](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-griddataitem-findcontrol.html)) or the previously mentioned `getElementsByTagName` as used above (looking for an `input` element) to find the checkbox control and update it's state.